# Setting up domain controller on windows 10

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain

I want to setup a Windows domain on Windows 10.
Actually I want to try using Active Directory Services on Windows 10, so it first needs a domain.

I can have another PC to be connected to my PC via Ethernet but it'll also have Windows 10.

I have searched a lot but I only find "Setup Domain on Windows Server" or "Join Domain on Windows 10" but not "Setup Domain on Windows 10". Is it possible in any way? or it is impossible?

Comment: You probably do not have the appropriate version of the OS to do what you want. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions

Answer (score 10):

Active Director requires a Domain Controller, which needs to be set up on a Windows Server operating system.

You can do this using Virtual Machines, though, [this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/51456-windows-server-2016-setup-local-domain-controller.html) looks like a decent tutorial.

Note that you will be installing **evaluation** versions of WIndows Server, which expire in 180 days.